# Conflicting return type in implementation of 'tableview:canEditRowAtIndexPath:'

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have just noticed this warning :

> Conflicting return type in implementation of
>   'tableview:canEditRowAtIndexPath:': 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char') vs
>   'bool'

This is how my implementation of this method looks like:

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSInteger row = indexPath.row;

    if (row >= 0 && row < messages.count){

        Message *message = [messages objectAtIndex:row];

        if (message){
            if ([message getSeen]){
                return YES;
            }
        }
    }

    return NO;
}
```

And this is how its declaration from UITableView.h looks like:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

What is the cause of this warning ?

Answer (score 1):

That shouldn't happen.  Check if there is a typedef or #define for BOOL somewhere in your code. Double-click on BOOL in your code, right-click and "Show definition".

Comment: Actually, it is a buggy Xcode. At first, I did analyze (Product -> Analyze) and that warning showed up. After every next build, the warning stayed. But when I did clean, and have re-built an app, the warning has disappeared. Luckily ... Because this would be a serious bug :)